# Barring entry to worker threads at workflow reconfiguration

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm struggling to find the correct Java thread synchronization mechanism for my use-case

1. a pool of an unknowable number of threads undertake work in a workflow
2. the workflow is reconfigured by some over-seer thread
3. during reconfiguration worker threads attempting to enter the workflow must be blocked.

Can anyone say how step 3 can be achieved?

[image: Barring threads to workflow during reconfiguration]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReentrantReadWriteLock` from `java.util.concurrent.locks` would fit to your needs.

> A read-write lock allows for a greater level of concurrency in
>   accessing shared data than that permitted by a mutual exclusion lock.
>   It exploits the fact that while only a single thread at a time (a
>   writer thread) can modify the shared data, in many cases any number of
>   threads can concurrently read the data (hence reader threads).

Worker threads should use `ReadLock` and "over-seer" thread `WriteLock`. While reconfiguration of workflow, write lock would block readers.

Here's sample code

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

class Workflow {

    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public void updateWorkflowConfig() {
        this.rwl.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            // do smth
        } finally {
            this.rwl.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public Work takeWorkFromWorkflow() {
        Work result = null;
        this.rwl.readLock().lock();
        try {
            result = //...
        } finally {
            this.rwl.readLock().unlock();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The worker threads are readers of the workflow configuration, the overseer is a writer.

Answer (score 0):

You could protect the workflow with a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) that is initialized with the same number of permits as you have threads in your pool. If a thread wants to start processing the workflow it must acquire a permit.

Your master thread that is configuring the workflow "drains" the semaphore by acquiring all permits. For this to work reliably you'd have to create the semaphore to be "fair". This has an impact on performance but will provide that worker threads cannot jump in an do another round of processing even though the master thread already requested all permits from the semaphore. As the master thread now holds all permits, your worker threads will all wait for a permit to become available so they can continue.

Once the master thread is done it obviously must release all permits that it acquired.

Comment: A good idea Ralph, but the size of the pool is unknowable. I shall clarify my question